# Javascript : How to test if a string contains an integer between 2 values?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm currently coding a discord bot using javascript and I want to test if a message contains an hour. I managed to do it this way

```
var content = msg.content.toLowerCase();    // Get the content on the message
const nbs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
var hours;
nbs.forEach(number => {
        if(content.includes(`${number}am`)) hours = `${number}AM`;  
        else if(content.includes(`${number}pm`)) hours = `${number}PM`;
})
```

But the problem I have is in this example I can't detect if the hour contains minutes like 10:15am for example. I thought about doing another array containing integers from 1 to 59 and doing another forEach inside the one I already have but I'm afraid it would slow the code down quite a bit.

Is there a way I could test if the message contains an int between 2 values so I could have something like this ?

```
content.includes(`${hr}:${min}am`)
```

Comment: use regular expression in match function like  content.match(/\d+/g);

Comment: @ArayniMax it would just store the content as all upper cases instead all lower cases it wouldn't change a whole lot I believe

Comment: @ShafeequeTP I'll have to learn how JS regular expression work, I'll try that thank you

Comment: @JohanDaniel go for it that will be worth your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```js
function getTime(message) {
    const result = message.match(/(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})\s*(am|pm)/i);

    if (result) {
        return {
            hours: Number(result[1]),
            minutes: Number(result[2]),
            format: result[3],
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

console.log(getTime("hello 2:13AM"));
console.log(getTime("hello 19:55 pm"));
console.log(getTime("hello"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular Expressions to get the time.
I would recommend using something like this:

```
/([0-2][0-9])\:([0-6][0-9])(?:\s*)?(am|pm)?/
```

I'll now go through all parts of this regular expression:

`([0-2][0-9])` - Using the first capturing group you will be able to get values from 00 to 24 (well 29 to be honest) but it will do the trick.

`\:` - will capture your seperator in this case a double colon

`([0-6][0-9])` - will capture a number between 00 to 69

`(?:\s*)?(am|pm)?` - last but not least capture am or pm. This is completely optional. The regex will also capture times without am or pm if someone writes in a 24 hour format

```js
let content = 'some content 10:00 AM ...';
content = content.toLowerCase();
console.log(content);

const time_regex = /([0-2][0-9])\:([0-6][0-9])(?:\s*)?(am|pm)?/;

if ((m = time_regex.exec(content)) !== null) {
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin', `<p>Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}</p>`);
    });
}
```

If you want to be even more specific and make sure that times like 26:00 or 13:65 are not possible to match you can adjust the regex like this

```
([0-2][0-9])(?<!25|26|27|28|29)\:([0-6][0-9])(?<!61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68|69)(?:\s*)?(am|pm)?
```

As you can see after the check for the values 00 to 29 and 00 to 69 I have added negative lookbehinds with all values we want to exclude. This makes sure that the first capturing group can only count up to 24 and the second can only count up to 60.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation ! I was trying to create a regex by myself but was lost